# Spicket or spigot?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, dialects, phonology

I recently was making a list and for the first time using a digital device, typed in what I grew up referring to an outdoor faucet 'spicket' as into my iPad.

My mother grew up in Utah and my father in. Nebraska, Utah, Wyoming and Idaho. Mom's parents in Salt Lake and Central Utah while Dad's parents in Tennessee and the Western states.

I looked up how to spell *spicket* and for the first time in my 35 year teaching career found again that I have been mispronouncing and misspelling a word.

I am wondering which parts of the country use *spigot* and who says *spicket*?

Who knew?

Comment: Related earlier question: [Why does “everyone” pronounce “spigot” as “spicket”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309561/why-does-everyone-pronounce-spigot-as-spicket)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95357/discussion-on-question-by-linda-spicket-or-spigot).

Comment: It's the *first time* that you *found again*?  Is that just a long-winded way of saying *second time*?

Comment: Ironically however you pronounce/spell it - it perhaps isn't the correct word as a spigot is a peg, plug or stopper not a tap or faucet (really only the "bung" part of a tap is the spigot rather the tap itself) - although that usage is given for the Appalachia area - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spigot#Etymology

Comment: related : [A Note on 'Spigot' and 'Spicket'](https://www.jstor.org/stable/487109?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: @TobySpeight It could mean, "Prior to my teaching career, I found out I had been misspelling certain words. Then, 35 years into my teaching career, I found yet another word that I have been misspelling."

Answer (score 30):

**spicket**

> Definition of *spicket*
>
> *chiefly South & Midland* [Middle USA] : **spigot**

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spicket))

> 41. [Do you use "spigot" or "spicket" to refer to a faucet or tap that water comes out of?](https://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_41.html)
>
>     a. spicket (6.38%)
>        
>     b. spigot (66.89%)
>        
>     c. I use both interchangeably (2.52%)
>        
>     d. I say "spicket" but spell it "spigot" (12.64%)

(Vaux, Bert and Scott Golder. 2003. [The Harvard Dialect Survey](https://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/index.html). Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Linguistics Department).

Comment: I'm from the South, and it's *spigit*.

Answer (score 5):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Just as /d/ and /t/ neutralize after a stressed vowel before an unstressed one (*writer/rider, catty/caddy*), so do /ɡ/ and /k/, and for the same reason -- vowels are voiced and tend to voice consonants between them, especially short consonants like voiceless stops. This means that it's very hard to hear the difference in that context, and therefore usually not worth making the effort to distinguish them in speech. It isn't, afaik, a geographic phenomenon, just a personal one, though it may be socioeconomic in some cases.

Comment: This doesn't happen in British English.  "Writer" is not pronounced like "rider".  The "t" is sounded like a "t".

Comment: @PhilRogers It's not common in American English either.  Neither is pronouncing 'catty' like 'caddy'.  I think it might be that when not being able to hear the difference between sounds is highly correlated to not being able to pronounce them.

Comment: Americans don't aspirate t's in the middle of words, which can make them sound like d's to an English ear. Americans say "right - er" not "rye- ter."

Comment: @TimGrant The rules for aspiration are more complex that that. It's aspirated at the start of a **stressed** syllable even midword: *satanic, spectacular, pretentious, potato, intention, catatonic*. And there are no flaps in *retentive*.

Comment: I don't think this explanation works. As Peter Shor says in on comment on the earlier question about *spicket/spigot,* we don't hear the same variation with most other words with *ck* or *g*: there aren't a bunch of people who think *bigot* sounds just like "bicket" (or *bucket* sound just like "bugget", or *trigger* sounds just like "tricker"). The neutralization of /d/ and /t/ is *not* normally accompanied by a neutralization of /g/ and /k/, so I don't see how that could explain the pronunciation of the specific word *spigot* as "spicket".

Comment: @sumelic And even if /g/ and /k/ were neutralised here, they are still distinct phonemes, and clipping would only occur before /k/.

Answer (score 3):

https://pittsburghspeech.pitt.edu/PittsburghSpeech_PgheseOverview.html

Spicket is very common in the "Pittsburghese" dialect spoken in western pennsylvania, but it is clearly a corruption of "spigot".

Comment: The OED has quite a few rather old citations of this word, with several from the 1600s and a couple dating back into the 1400s. How then is it “clearly” a “corruption”?

Comment: @tchrist The OED also clearly notes its etymology as an *alteration of spigot*.

Answer (score 0):

In my 67 years growing up middle class in North Carolina, the word in question was commonly understood to be spelled *spigot* and pronounced *spickit*.